# How to make a chapter heading like this in latex

Tags: pdftex, chapters, thesis

How can I make a chapter heading like this in latex?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the [titlesec package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec).

Comment: @Thruston Not really a duplicate I'd say. The style is different, and there is no chapter abstract in this case.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. But if OP keep asking one-line questions, it is duplicating.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a good question, but it's not a duplicate of the one link to either, IMO.

Comment: I don't think it is correct to close this one. Rather, it's correct to ignore it. Because there's no purpose in answering these zero-effort questions again and again.